# How to do if else in gitlab-ci to execute different script on the same job?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, maven-3

I have the following job:

```
variables:
    MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=false -DdeployAtEnd=false -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener='warn"


package:
  stage: package
  extends: .jdk_in_dind
  script:
    - ./builddockerimage.sh -a
    - docker save -o candy-manager-docker-image-`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`.tgz  track-history-manager:`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`
    - chmod 777 candy-manager-docker-image-`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`.tgz
    - mvn clean ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} package
    - ls -la target
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - candy-manager-*.tgz
      - target/candy-manager*.jar
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - develop
    - tags
    - prod
```

I was wandering if I can use rules to add a tag number when a tag is generated on the tag.
here is the desired output

if tag is created, the tag should be read from CI_COMMIT_TAG global variable and have this outcome candy-manager_0.1.1_MYTAGVAULUE.jar if there is not tag and it's a regular commit then have the jar file as follow candy-manager_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar. the value 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT is read from 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT that is present from pom.xml.

I try the following technic:

```
package:
  stage: package
  extends: .jdk_in_dind

variables:
    MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=false -DdeployAtEnd=false -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener='warn"

rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != ""'
      when: 
MAVEN_CLI_OPTS = "-s $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/settings.xml --batch-mode versions:set -DnewVersion=${CI_COMMIT_TAG} --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=false -DdeployAtEnd=false -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener='warn"

  script:
    - ./builddockerimage.sh -a
    - docker save -o candy-manager-docker-image-`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`.tgz  track-history-manager:`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`
    - chmod 777 candy-manager-docker-image-`docker images candy-manager --format "{{.Tag}}"`.tgz
    - mvn clean ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} package
    - ls -la target
```

but it is not working.

any help on this.

Comment: Ah... and what is exactly not working? What are the outputs? Which Maven version, JDK etc. do you se?

Comment: openjdk version "12.0.2"

apache-maven-3.6.3

The error message I see is 

* jobs:package:rules:rule:variables config should be a hash of key value pairs

Comment: First JDK 12 (non LTS) (JDK17 LTS) is already out of date as well as Maven 3.6.3 (most recent 3.8.6)